# Apply pseudo-element CSS selector inside shadow DOM

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, pseudo-element, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

I have a Polymer 2 `paper-input` that holds a date:

```
<paper-input type="date"></paper-input>
```

When this renders the actual `<input>` is inside the shadow DOM for the control.

I want to use the pseudo-element selector `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` to style the spinner buttons in Chrome.

In Polymer 1/Shadow DOM v0 I could use `/deep/` or `::shadow` to build a style rule for these, but those have been deprecated in Polymer 2/Shadow DOM v1.

How do I apply a style to a pseudo-element inside the `<paper-input>`'s shadow DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--paper-input-container-input-webkit-spinner` custom css mixin [have a look at this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties).

For instance, hide the spinner:

```
paper-input[type=date] {
    --paper-input-container-input-webkit-spinner: {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
}
```